# Entering stops in published multimodal ArcGIS network service?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, network-analyst, multimodal-network

I have created a multimodal network that works fine in Desktop, but my question is more related to publishing a multimodal network dataset as a network service. I have looked for an example of this, but have failed to find one. When the multimodal dataset is published, I have entered x,y coordinates already confirmed and working in Desktop, yet I am receiving an error when I try to return the route saying the stops are not valid.

Do I need to send an attribute with the feature to identify which mode that geometry should snap to?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 REST API.

Comment: I think you do need to specify which lines the points should snap to, because I have had that error several times, and only after zooming in very close I saw that the newly added stops were not snapped to a transport line.